# Background Music in Adobe Flash keeps duplicating?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I have a problem with my background music.
So I added this code on frame 1:

```
var bmsound:Sound = new backgroundmusic();
var channel:SoundChannel;
channel=bmsound.play(0,10000);
```

And it works like a charm. The problem is, when I navigate to other frames and go back to frame 1 again, the music plays again, so there are two sounds playing in the background. Everytime I go back to frame 1 it plays the music again so there are a lot of sounds playing in the background.
How do I fix it? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because everytime you navigate back to Frame 1, the code is activated once again. To avoid playing it again, I suggest to have a variable of `Number` or `Boolean` type named "musicPlaying" and modify your code this way:

```
var channel: SoundChannel;


if (!musicPlaying) {
  var bmsound: Sound = new backgroundmusic();
  channel = bmsound.play(0, 10000);
  musicPlaying = true;
}
```

This way, you can stop the music from repeating again.

Initialize the musicPlaying in a starting a new Frame before Frame 1 , making the current Frame 1 as Frame 2 and add this code in the new Frame 1:

```
  var musicPlaying: Boolean = false;
```

All I could think was this.

Comment: In fact, the line `var musicPlaying: Boolean = false;` should also reset the flag as soon as frame 1 is reached once again. But, you can use the default assignment of false to any declared `Boolean` variable to just declare `var musicPlaying: Boolean;` and then assigning it to `true` in the following if statement. This way it shouldn't break. Still, I'd rather place the music initialization into the constructor instead of timeline.

Comment: Yep, also you should relocate `bmsound = new backgroundmusic();` into the if statement as well, due to constant creation of `Sound` object, while you need only one.

Comment: @Vesper Oh yes I realized it just now. I've edited the code you said. Thanks.

Comment: But I do agree with @Vesper that placing it in the constructor is a better option.